# Is there something like a "peer-review paper"?

Tags: peer-review, open-science

Journals like CVPR (IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition) have a peer-reviewing process. Depending on the journal (or the publication published after a conference - is that also called a journal?) one might simply know that all articles were peer-reviewed.

However, those reviews are not publicly available as far as I know.

This is also a problem of arXiv / bad journals. They might have (many) good articles, but one has to check them. A work-around might be to look at citation counts / who cited the article, but citations are not necessarily positive.

Are there any typical / recommended ways to write reviews and make them publicly available?

Comment: I'd be very cautious about publishing your reviews. Any review leading to a rejection is going to annoy some people and there's a decent chance this will come back to haunt you -- when those same people review your paper or grant application. I also think it's discourteous toward the authors of the paper: you're pointing out everything that's wrong with it and give them no chance to respond.

Comment: @user2898391 I think there are ways to fix the problems you've mentioned: Anonymous reviews, first sending the review to the authors, formulation of the review itself, a change of "reviewing culture".

Comment: @moose Stack Exchange sites are here to answer reasonably scoped, well-defined questions, not to discuss how to change the culture of an area.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I know what StackExchange sites are designed for. I never said we should do so here. In fact, I never said it should be done. I only said that the mentioned problems can be fixed and explained 4 ways to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on whether you want to leave short comments on papers you weren't invited to review or make public full reviews of papers that you were, you might look at http://www.pubpeer.com and http://www.publons.com respectively.

Comment: Or if you want the reviews on your own submitted manuscripts to be open, there are places like http://f1000research.com/

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention the arxiv, you might be interested in [Episciences](http://www.episciences.org/), which aims at enabling what you describe, although I don't know what the current status of the project is.